# use function to choose between return or throw

Tags: javascript

I have the following switch statement in several places in my code:

```
try {
   ...
} catch(e) {
   switch(x){
      case A:
         throw e;
      default:
         return e;
   }
}
```

I would love to be able to wrap it in a function like this:

```
function handle(e) {
   switch(x) {
      case A:
         throw e;
      default:
         return e;
   }
}

try {
   ...
} catch(e) {
   handle(e);
}
```

I know the above case doesn't work (the code executing "handle" still doesn't throw or return anything) but it would be really nice to make the code a little more DRY.

Comment: Sorry, need to check, yes `return handle(e);` should work. Throw steps out of the standard execution flow and well throws, to the return is only to return the result if the throw doesn't happen.

Comment: any time you get to a `throw` statement, the normal flow is interrupted an an exception is thrown. So, yes, `return handle(e)` can indeed throw or return as appropriate.

Comment: @Liam Thanks, today I learned something new! Post is as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: TBh I can't be bothered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, this shouldn't be a problem. Your example is a bit generic (e. g.: What is `A` and `x`? Do they need to be passed or can you derive them from the error?), so this example provides a general "solution" as well which (hopefully) suits your needs.

You could consider creating a "error-case" handler for various types of errors. The handler only every `throw`s the error, if it cannot find a defined error case.

```js
// Higher-order function to create "error handlers":
function handleBy (cases) {
  return function (err) {
    if (cases[err.constructor.name]) {
      return cases[err.constructor.name](err);
    }
    throw err;
  }
}


// create an error handler which returns different "defaults" or "fallbacks"
// for certain types of errors. alternatively, it returns the error itself
var handleRead = handleBy({
  TypeError: function (err) {
    return 'default value';
  },
  SyntaxError: function (err) {
    return err;
  }
});


// this is the action to be guarded
var unsafeAction = function () {
  try {
    return window.foo.bar;
  } catch (e) {
    return handleRead(e);
  }
}

console.log(unsafeAction())
```